# Android Device Purchase and Testing

Tags: android, device, screen-size

My company needs to get devices (maximum four for now) to start testing the Android applications. I know there are four screen sizes according to the Android developers forum,

1. X-large
2. Large
3. Medium
4. Small

How can one shop for 4 different devices belonging to the four different categories. How do I know if a Samsung Galaxy s2 for example belongs to the "Large" or the "Medium" family?

Any recommendations for what device to get in each category would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). It exactly shows what you can expect from multiple screen sizes, and how you can design for them.

> xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
>   large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
>   normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
>   small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

See also this rough illustration:
[image]

You would be good with a smartphone (3"-4"), a 7" tablet, and a 10" tablet.

Answer (score 2):

You should watch the Google IO 2012 talk with Reto Meier "[Making Good Apps Great](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PwC1OlJo5VM)" as he discusses exactly this problem from about 45 minutes in.

As he mentions you can't just buy devices with different sceeen sizes, as pixels are irrelevant, because of pixel density. For instance the Galaxy Nexus, One X and Nexus 7 all have the same screen resolution but in a different form factor.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the screen size qualification you are talking about but I'd expect there are actually more than four different screen resolutions available, ranging up to 1280x800 (Galaxy Note). I would try to refer to the screen sizes using the 'graphics array' < http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphic_display_resolutions>.

Just look at some popular models from different price ranges and you'll be able to find out the common resolutions. Also, you could have a look at what resolutions the android emulator which is coming with the SDK suggests.

Conceirning the shopping, I'd just pick one manufacturer, like Samsung or HTC, and pick devices from different prize ranges with different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

The screen size is not the only thing that matters. There is also the pixel density property.

However, you don't need to start buying every possible device. It's best to focus on the common configuration that you can see here (scroll down to screen sizes and densities):

http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

So the most common is normal/hdpi which is around 4" screen and 240dp density. normal/mdpi is next but that's probably in decline.

lagre/mdpi and xlarge/mdpi are tablets and normal/xhdpi is today's super-phones like galaxy s3.